# Can I import everything from a javascript library with parcelJS?

Tags: javascript, frontend, highlight.js, parceljs

I recently started using [parcelJS](https://parceljs.org) to build and I'm pretty new to Webpack and such tools. I use the [highlighJS](https://highlightjs.org/) library to highlight some syntax on my page and I'm importing it using the line below.

```
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/highlight';
```

This library also has languages that to highlight the syntax which can be imported using:

```
import python from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/python';
```

Is there a way to import all of the languages in the folder instead of importing them one by one?

Comment: have you tried just `import hljs from 'highlight.js'`? their documentation says 'The default import imports all languages!' so it may work

Answer (score 0):

Using `import hljs from 'highlight.js'` imports all the languages and functions in highlightJS when using `hljs.highlightBlock(vnode.dom);` syntax is automatically detected and highlighted and there is no need to register a language.